# Submitting form via multiple partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a really long form which I would like to break up into about 5 partials.  When the user hits 'Next' at the bottom of each partial I want to use AJAX to load the next partial until the last partial submits the entire form into the database.  Also, if the user hits 'Previous' I need the fields to be populated with what the user filled in previously.

So far I have this which is not working:

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit "Next" %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { flash[:success] = "Welcome to Friends First!"
                  redirect_to @user }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#site_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('layouts/partial2')) %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put each of the 5 parts into separate divs (display: none) and only show (display: block) the first. When the user clicks "next", I would show the second, etc. The final submit to the create action can also be done via jquery through

```
$.ajax(
  url: '/users',
  type: 'post',
  data: $("form").serialize()
)
```

I hope, that helps.